# Angular4 difference componentInstance and debugElement.componentInstance

Tags: angular, testing

I just went through the doc over there https://angular.io/guide/testing

```
component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance
component = fixture.componentInstance
```

But I am yet to understand the difference between these two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. `TestBed.createComponent` creates an instance of component class, both properties refer to it:

```
fixture.debugElement.componentInstance === fixture.componentInstance
```

`fixture.componentInstance` can be preferred because it takes less time to type.